# Hyper-v manager different domains

Tags: hyper-v, replication, hyper-v-server-2012

I have two offices each have there own domain.
Domain-A
Domain-B

Each site has its own windows 2012 R2 HyperV GUI server.
The sites are connected using SonicWall persistent VPN's

Id like to use each site as a DR solution.
I would like to use the Hyperv replication feature to do this.

Presently, cant add the remote server in hyperv manager.
Any and all suggestions appreciated

thanks
Mike

Comment: `Presently, cant add the remote server in hyperv manager`. Seriously?! What can we do with this information? You gave us absolutely no details whatsoever. Does this strike you as a professional level question? Does this strike you as a question that we're even remotely capable of answering based on what you've given us? How about putting some effort into your question.

Comment: `Any and all suggestions appreciated` - Here's a suggestion: Read the FAQ and pay careful attention to the information regarding writing a quality question. Then come back and rewrite your question with enough detail that we can actually attempt to answer it.

Comment: Your question as written is equivalent to this: "My car doesn't work. What could be wrong?"

Answer (score 0):

In Hyper-V, when you "Enable this computer as a Replica server", Check "Use certificate-based Authentication (HTTPS)" and not "Use Kerberos".

Configure certificates and name resolution. This article should get tyou where you need to be:

https://nerddrivel.com/2016/03/07/hyper-v-replication-in-a-workgroup-or-across-domains-using-a-self-signed-certificate/